# HotKeys for Mac OS

Tags: shortcut, osx

Super new to Blender and having trouble finding good information on HotKey shortcuts for Mac. For some reason, none of my keyboard letters shortcuts will work: ie. <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> etc. won't trigger anything inside Blender.

I'm currently stuck trying to Grab an object, but without my hotkeys working I can't even find the grab tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> then click on "Keymap" and on the right side you will find all shortcuts and you can define your own one.

Just e.g. <kbd>G</kbd> works if you selected an object before, then you can move an object with your mouse -> this will work in other panels too like timeline...

<kbd>A</kbd> will select all objects in Viewport and outliner ...and nearly each panel.

<kbd>D</kbd> is for moving in navigation modes in viewport.

Maybe you should watch some beginner tutorials - all free - https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Comment: Bless You. That did the trick! Will definitely watch these tutorials!

Comment: Please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. Thank you.